# TravisCi Android missing licenses

Tags: android, gradle, travis-ci, fastlane

we're trying to build our react native app for android on Travis-ci with fastlane, the build fails

I have tried everything online and my current travis.yml looks like that:

```
matrix:
  include:
  - language: android
    android:
      components:
        - tools
        - build-tools-26.0.1
        - build-tools-25.0.1
        - build-tools-25.0.2
        - build-tools-25.0.3
        - build-tools-24.0.1
        - build-tools-23.0.1
        - android-26
        - android-25
        - android-24
        - android-23
        - extra
        - tools
      licenses:
          - 'android-sdk-license-.+'
          - 'google-gdk-license-.+'
          - 'build-tools-.+'
```

I tried a lot of things but always end up with the following errors

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_devDebugApk'.
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-onesignal'.
      > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
        [Android SDK Build-Tools 25].
        Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
        Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
```

I am not sure what `Android SDK Build-Tools 25` is in terms of `build-tool-xxx` `tools` `android-xxx`. Anyone knows how to know what to accept exactly?

Comment: Exporting licenses from a local computer worked but I would still like to know how to fix it otherwise....

https://devcenter.bitrise.io/troubleshooting/frequent-android-issues/#alternative-solution-for-the-license-error